# Как упростить данный селектор CSS?

Tags: css

```
.contacts form .name, .contacts form .email, .contacts form .message {
   ...
}
```

как написать такой селектор компактнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

отдельный класс завести для инпутов в формах .form__input

Answer (score 0):

Просто для инпута пропишите стили `input { стили }` в таком случае вы зададите стили всем полям инпут. Если у вас несколько форм и у инпутов в них должны быть разные стили тогда `.contacts-1 input { стили }` стили для первой формы, `.contacts-2 input { стили }` стили для второй формы и так далее.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно сделать так:

```css
.contacts form [class|=xxx] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="contacts">

  <form>

    <input class="xxx-name">

    <br>
    <br>

    <input class="xxx-email">

    <br>
    <br>

    <textarea class="xxx-message"></textarea>

  </form>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4h0cqgfd/

---

Подробнее о селекторе `[атрибут|="значение"]` читайте здесь: https://webref.ru/css/selector/attr7 .

Comment: Хм.. Но зачем??

Comment: @Qwertiy, например, для группировки: следующую группу сделать `yyy`. Но вообще я, в частности, не часто подобный селектор использую, но случаи бывали; какие конкретно уже не помню, но помню использовал.

Comment: Я имел в виду, почему бы просто не повесить отдельный класс `xxx` и сделать селектор `.contacts form .xxx`, а то и просто `.xxx`. Зачем эти выкрутасы с `[class|=xxx]`?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, можно и так, и ещё куча вариантов — я привёл просто один из них; а конкретно, как вы и сами понимаете, — нужно смотреть по ситуации и делать как наглядней, удобней и так далее.